# Elasticsearch does not respond sometimes during indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to index a MySQL table with 1 million rows in Elasticsearch. I trying this through PHP with the foreach loop. But after a while Elasticsearch is not responding and the process is clogging. I tried some configurations, but it did not work. I think ElasticSearch can not reach the speed of PHP. Is there someone who has encountered this problem before? How can I solve this problem?

My elasticsearch configuration;

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
indices.fielddata.cache.size:  40%
http.max_content_length: 1024mb
indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec: 1024mb
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 50%
min_index_buffer_size: 512mb
max_index_buffer_size: 24gb
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 512mb
indices.recovery.concurrent_streams: 30
indices.recovery.file_chunk_size: 256mb
indices.recovery.translog_ops: 10000
indices.recovery.translog_size: 256mb
indices.recovery.compress: true
indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec: 1gb
```

Comment: Could you share your mapping and data to sampling situation? And Are you using bulk insert or one by one insert?

Comment: Here is my code snippets.

http://prntscr.com/ee2yb2

http://prntscr.com/ee2y1n

http://prntscr.com/ee2zuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Invalidating Refresh Interval

> The refresh API allows to explicitly refresh one or more index, making all operations performed since the last refresh available for search. The (near) real-time capabilities depend on the index engine used. For example, the internal one requires refresh to be called, but by default a refresh is scheduled periodically.

There is a `refresh_interval` configuration of elasticsearch. This feature can coordinate your refresh actions. You can set this interval to -1 to invalidate it while indexing large dataset.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "-1"
    } }'
```

With this change, your bulk indexing will faster. In this case, now you should refresh your indices, manually. After indexing your data, you need to change your configuration back.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "1s"
    } }'
```

Have you tried before?

### Bulk Indexing

You can use bulk API if you can index multiple data at the same time. You can gain some performance with bulk actions. Because you will go to api one instead of many times. This will increase the indexing speed greatly. You can find an example request about bulk indexing below:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

### Storage

Elasticsearch  heavily use disks, so storage is so important. Because it can be bottleneck for you if not using SSD.

For more information please check [the indexing performance tips](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/indexing-performance.html) article. It will really help you.

Comment: Is a document of your data large (For example, ten key and nested data set. twenty keys and nested, etc)? Are you using mapping for your types? Because analyzing operations will be slower your indexing. And you are using one by one indexing. Bulk insert will help you about faster indexing. Have you tried bulk indexing before?

Comment: On the other hand, is your disk SSD?

Comment: No, it's not SSD. I did not try bulk indexing and I have no idea about this.

Comment: Are you using elasticsearch-php library to connect ES?